# What is the value of data members of an object initialized through member initializer list. Specifically What would be values of x and y?

Tags: c++

When i run this program the output is "In A" and "In Show". Why cout statements after that are not printing ? I am initializing class B object using member initializer list so the value of of x and y should ideally be 0. Why is this strange behavior ?

```
class B
{
    int x, y;
public:
    B(int a)
    {

    }
    void show() //what would this print ?
    {
        cout << "In Show";
        cout << "x = " << x << endl;
        cout << "y =" << y;
    }
};

class A
{
    B *b;
public:
    A() : b(0)
    {
        cout << "In A";
        b->show();
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Partial duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30180417/why-does-an-uninitialized-variable-print-in-c and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30542801/reading-uninitialized-variable

Comment: *"I am initializing class B object using member initializer list so the value of of x and y should ideally be 0."* - Where do you initialize `class B`?

Comment: Even if you would initialize `A::b` with the address of a valid instance of `B` (maybe like `A() : b{ new B{42} } {}`, `b.x` and `b.y` would still contain garbage because they are not initialized with a value in `B`s constructor. They will get *default-initialized* which means simpy: do nothing for `int`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are initializing the pointer `b` with `0`, then try to dereference this `0` with `b->show()`.

This is undefined behavior and the fact that anything is printed at all is pure luck.

You need to initialize `b` with a pointer to a valid `B` object, for example by allocating one with `new B`, although I highly advice not to use dynamic memory as a C++ beginner if avoidable.

Considering the rest of your code, probably you simply want `b` to have type `B` instead of `B*`.

If you really want an owning pointer there prefer `std::unique_ptr<B>` over `B*`.

Additionally you are not actually initializing `B`s members to zero in its constructor. Their values would be indeterminate when `show` is called. To initialize them to zero you would need something like:

```
B(int a) : x(0), y(0)
{
}
```

or if both are supposed to be initialized to the value of `a`, then:

```
B(int a) : x(a), y(a)
{
}
```

Comment: Also he could use `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr` if he needs dynamic memory